# How to fix the stuttering when moving ThirdPersonController in unity?

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

When i move my character around the whol scene is stuttering. Only when i move the character. If the character stand not moving it's fine. Once i use keys W S D A it's stuttering.

I read in one answer that someone asked before that the camera handling part should be in the LateUpdate function. I have a LateUpdate function in this script so i'm not sure where is the problem.

The answer from 2013 was " Put you camera handling code in LateUpdate. That way you'll move your players object in the Update method and the camera will trail him in the LateUpdate method. I had the same issue when I had camera follow code AND character movement code both happening inside of Update. "

In Main Camera in the spector i have this CameraScript in c#:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraScript : MonoBehaviour {


    public Transform TargetLookAt;

    public float Distance = 5.0f;
    public float DistanceMin = 3.0f;
    public float DistanceMax = 10.0f;

    private float mouseX = 0.0f;
    private float mouseY = 0.0f;
    private float startingDistance = 0.0f;    
    private float desiredDistance = 0.0f;

    public float X_MouseSensitivity = 5.0f;
    public float Y_MouseSensitivity = 5.0f;
    public float MouseWheelSensitivity = 5.0f;
    public float Y_MinLimit = -40.0f;
    public float Y_MaxLimit = 80.0f;

    public float DistanceSmooth = 0.05f;    
    private float velocityDistance = 0.0f;    
    private Vector3 desiredPosition = Vector3.zero;

    public float X_Smooth = 0.05f;
    public float Y_Smooth = 0.1f;
    private float velX = 0.0f;
    private float velY = 0.0f;
    private float velZ = 0.0f;
    private Vector3 position = Vector3.zero;

    CursorLockMode wantedMode;    


    void  Start (){
        Distance = Mathf.Clamp(Distance, DistanceMin, DistanceMax);
        startingDistance = Distance;
        Reset();
        SetCursorState();
        OnGUI();

    }

    void  LateUpdate (){
        if (TargetLookAt == null)
            return;

        HandlePlayerInput();

        CalculateDesiredPosition();

        UpdatePosition();
    }

    void  HandlePlayerInput (){
        float deadZone= 0.01f; // mousewheel deadZone

        //if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
        //{
        mouseX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * X_MouseSensitivity;
        mouseY -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * Y_MouseSensitivity;
        //}

        // this is where the mouseY is limited - Helper script
        mouseY = ClampAngle(mouseY, Y_MinLimit, Y_MaxLimit);

        // get Mouse Wheel Input
        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") < -deadZone || Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") > deadZone)
        {
            desiredDistance = Mathf.Clamp(Distance - (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") * MouseWheelSensitivity), 
                DistanceMin, DistanceMax);
        }
    }

    void  CalculateDesiredPosition (){
        // Evaluate distance
        Distance = Mathf.SmoothDamp(Distance, desiredDistance, ref velocityDistance, DistanceSmooth);

        // Calculate desired position -> Note : mouse inputs reversed to align to WorldSpace Axis
        desiredPosition = CalculatePosition(mouseY, mouseX, Distance);
    }

    Vector3  CalculatePosition ( float rotationX ,   float rotationY ,   float distance  ){
        Vector3 direction = new Vector3(0, 0, -distance);
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotationX, rotationY, 0);
        return TargetLookAt.position + (rotation * direction);
    }

    void  UpdatePosition (){
        float posX= Mathf.SmoothDamp(position.x, desiredPosition.x, ref velX, X_Smooth);
        float posY= Mathf.SmoothDamp(position.y, desiredPosition.y, ref velY, Y_Smooth);
        float posZ= Mathf.SmoothDamp(position.z, desiredPosition.z, ref velZ, X_Smooth);
        position = new Vector3(posX, posY, posZ);

        transform.position = position;

        transform.LookAt(TargetLookAt);
    }

    void  Reset (){
        mouseX = 0;
        mouseY = 10;
        Distance = startingDistance;
        desiredDistance = Distance;
    }

    float ClampAngle ( float angle ,   float min ,   float max  ){
        while (angle < -360 || angle > 360)
        {
            if (angle < -360)
                angle += 360;
            if (angle > 360)
                angle -= 360;
        }

        return Mathf.Clamp(angle, min, max);
    }

    // Apply requested cursor state
    void SetCursorState ()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = wantedMode;
        // Hide cursor when locking
        Cursor.visible = (CursorLockMode.Locked != wantedMode);
    }

    void OnGUI ()
    {
        GUILayout.BeginVertical ();
        // Release cursor on escape keypress
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Escape))
            Cursor.lockState = wantedMode = CursorLockMode.None;

        switch (Cursor.lockState) {
        case CursorLockMode.None:
            GUILayout.Label ("Cursor is normal");
            if (GUILayout.Button ("Lock cursor"))
                wantedMode = CursorLockMode.Locked;
            if (GUILayout.Button ("Confine cursor"))
                wantedMode = CursorLockMode.Confined;
            break;
        case CursorLockMode.Confined:
            GUILayout.Label ("Cursor is confined");
            if (GUILayout.Button ("Lock cursor"))
                wantedMode = CursorLockMode.Locked;
            if (GUILayout.Button ("Release cursor"))
                wantedMode = CursorLockMode.None;
            break;
        case CursorLockMode.Locked:
            GUILayout.Label ("Cursor is locked");
            if (GUILayout.Button ("Unlock cursor"))
                wantedMode = CursorLockMode.None;
            if (GUILayout.Button ("Confine cursor"))
                wantedMode = CursorLockMode.Confined;
            break;
        }

        GUILayout.EndVertical ();

        SetCursorState ();
    }
}
```

Comment: ideally, you should never use LateUpdate. it's not the "real solution", you know?

Comment: I found now that once i drag the CameraScript into the Main Camera and run the game there is a error in the script file: AICharacterControl.cs at line 31: if (agent.remainingDistance > agent.stoppingDistance) the error is: "GetRemainingDistance" can only be called on an active agent that has been placed on a NavMesh.
UnityEngine.NavMeshAgent:get_remainingDistance()
UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson.AICharacterControl:Update() (at Assets/Standard Assets/Characters/ThirdPersonCharacter/Scripts/AICharacterControl.cs:31)

Comment: I'm not sure if this error is what making the stuttering problem. But i created a new project now with AIThirdPersonController and ThirdPersonController and Main Camera and once i drag the CameraScript to the Main Camera and once when i move the ThirdPersonController character with the keys W S D A it's stuttering. If i just use the mouse and turn the cmaera 360 degrees it's fine the stuttering happen only when making the character move with the keys.

Comment: Does this issue reproduces without LookAt() method call? Try to do only position change

Comment: Nno the problem is not with the camera script since i tried another camera script and got the same stuttering when moving the character.